# Tree data structure implementation using c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I have given below assignment by my teacher to implement but I am not sure what can be effective approach to implement the same. I will appreciate if somebody share pointers to proceed further.

**Problem description**:
Assume a tree object having a depth of "n" (n is a known number). For the sake of simplicity, it can be assumed that each node in the tree is a simple string. The number of siblings and children for each node and at each level could be a variable number. It can also be assumed that there will be an API which can return us the number of children for each node (A dummy API can be used which returns a random whole number for this exercise). Also, each parent node has a node number range associated with it. The children of that parent will have node numbers which fall in the parent range. In effect:
1. Each node will have a range (whole number) to identify its children
2. Each node will also have a unique node number to identify itself
With these requirements in place, design the following:
1. The tree data structure
2. An efficient numbering algorithm for the tree nodes
The tree should support the following operations:

1. Insertion of individual nodes at any level
2. Bulk insertion of nodes at any level (As far as possible, bulk insertion should not result in any renumbering of any parent/sibling node number ranges)

Comment: I didn't down vote this, but this looks like you're just trying to get us to do your homework for you. Try making your question more specific: what exactly would you like help with? What have you tried so far?

Comment: One way of numbering would be to take the parent node number * 10 + nr children + 1. So for the root the number would be 1. For the next nodes under the root it would be 1 * 10 + 1 ==> 11 for the first node,12 for the next etc.  This ensure uniqueness. But then I don't know whether this satisfy the constraint of the range.